# paste PS5.5 selection into Ai 6.0

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have selected part of an image and I would like to paste that selection into an open Illustrator document.
Basically a psd on top of a vector frame. The original image is a psd as I have already trimmed away the background and saved the selection as a psd. When I try to get the selection into Illustrator the paste/import commands fill the background with a paper color. Unacceptable. I just forgot how to do this. Help?
Suggestions?

Comment: Do you *really* mean AI6 or do you mean AI CS6? They are different products and have different capabilities.

Comment: Hahahahaha, Scott you are soo correct.!

Comment: Sorry, hit enter and posted incomplete response. I meant Ai CS6. I used your suggestion of placing and got my results. My image was RGB and my vector had been set up CMYK which I had paid no attention to at the start. Changed the image to CMYK and were good to place. It's time to clean the cobwebs from my machine and my brain. Thanks Scott for a prompt, correct response as well as the clarifying querry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Place** or link to the PSD rather than pasting it.